# How do I stay on the same page after closing popup?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, pagination, backend

I'm working with a PWA where scans are recorded in a Scan History Report Page. On the page, there are multiple entries. When I click on a scan from page 5 the details appear and when I close that scan the page gets reset to 1. I want to stay on page 5 after I close the scan details. This is the URL that it hits when I close the scan details:

```
api/v1/reports/scanHistoryListing/?pageSize=50&page=1&getTotalPages=true&sortOrder=1&status=2&fromDate=${fromDate.toDateString()}&toDate=${toDate.toDateString()}`
```

you can see that it defaults to page 1 when I hit close. This is my component:

```
/**
     * lazyLoad() is called when the table component requires data to display.
     * @param event A LazyLoadEvent object. Indicates the offset and length of data to be returned.
     */
    public lazyLoad(event: LazyLoadEvent): void {
        // Ensure all data is available.
        if (event.first == null || event.rows == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Work out the page we need to load.
        const page = Math.floor(event.first / event.rows) + 1;

        this.currentPage = page;
        // Read the data for the required page.
        this._reportService.scanHistoryListing(page, event.rows, this._generatedReportCriteria, this._getTotalRecords).subscribe((response) => {
            // If this is the first call for the report, store total records.
            if (this._getTotalRecords) {
                this.reportTotalRecords = response.totalRecords;
                this._getTotalRecords = false;
            }

            this.reportData = response.data;
        });
    }


public onCloseEvent(): void {
        this.displayMain = true;
        this.displayDetails = false;
    }


public onPage(event: LazyLoadEvent): void {
        if (event.first !== undefined && event.rows !== undefined && event.rows !== 0) {
            this.currentPage = event.first / event.rows + 1;
        } else {
            // Handle the case where event.first or event.rows is undefined or event.rows is 0
            // For example, you can set currentPage to a default value or handle the error accordingly.
        }
}
```

I've tried changing the request URL to page 2 just for testing purposes but that didn't work. I'm not quite sure where to go from here. I can add my HTML if needed.